# How to get data from Database/Model with JavaScript/AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new to ASP .NET, MVC and AngularJS so I'm trying to figure this all out still.

I have a Model called **Words.cs** which contains:

```
namespace liveSearch.Models
{
    public class Words
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Word{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

The database is already populated with data and I want to use JavaScript/JQuery to get every **Word** from the database and then use AngularJS to display that on my index.cshtml page.

I currently have Razor in my **index.cshtml** which does:

```
@{
     foreach (var item in Model)
     {
         <li>
             @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Word)
         </li>
     }
 }
```

This works in getting and displaying all Words in the model but I want to get rid of the Razor and use JavaScript/Jquery to get the data and AngularJS to display it there.

Ideally, I want to get all Words from the DB (I don't care about the IDs) and add it to an array in the scope. Then I can use AngularJS to display each Word by using `ng-repeat`.

The problem is that I don't know how to get all the Words into an array in the scope from the DB/model.

I think I can use `$.get()` or `$.ajax()` but I don't really know how to use it with a DB/model.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Angular is a client side technology. .Net is server side. Your .net code will have to be changed to an API that the Angular code will be able to use. I suggest you read up on WebApi to creat a RESTful service that your Angular code can then consume.

Comment: Ok forget about Angular. Can I at least get the DB data using JavaScript/JQuery?

Comment: JavaScript and jQuery are also client side technologies. They'll still require a RESTful API (or equivalent) from the server side. It's worth the investment to learn it.